# Combine and average each 15 data.frames from a list

Tags: r, list, data.table

My dataset is a list with 1000 elements of type data.frame ("sportdata"). Each data.frame element of the list represents one minute of data and has exactly the same number & names of columns and each data.frame has a maximum of 45 ID's (i.e. 45 rows, but in some minutes one or more ID's is missing, so it could be e.g. 35 rows). **I want to combine and average the complete data set per 15 data.frames, add this in one data.frame and transpose the data.frame so that I've the ID's as columns and the average SpeedKph per 15min as rows.**

My list of data.frames looks like this:

```
head(sportdata)
        [[1]]
                ID  Distance SpeedKph
         1:     1     2247       73
         2:     2     2247       73
         3:     3     1970       73
         4:     4     1964       74 
         5:     5     1971       73 
        [[2]]
                ID  Distance SpeedKph
         1:     1     2247       73
         2:     2     2247       75
         3:     3     1970       73
         4:     4     1964       74 
         5:     5     1971       73 
        [[3]]
                ID  Distance SpeedKph
         1:     1     2247       73
         2:     2     2247       80
         3:     3     1970       73
         4:     4     1964       74 
         5:     5     1971       56
```

I have the code below to combine and average all the data.frames from my list, but I haven't found a way to combine and average the list per 15 elements (i.e. 15 minutes) and add this in one data.frame.

```
dfTotal <- rbindlist(sportdata)[,lapply(.SD,mean), list(ID)]
```

I want my ideal output data.frame to look like:

```
   #ofData.Frames |   1   |  2  |  3  |...etc.
         01-15:      73     74    74
         16-30:      75     77    74
         31-45:      74     74    79
         46-60:      78     72    74
         ...etc.
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**
Sorry for not doing this directly, hereby my reproducible example.

```
my.df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5),
                    Distance = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971),
                    SpeedKph = c(73,73,74,73,75))
my.df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5),
                     Distance = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971),
                     SpeedKph = c(73,73,74,73,75))
my.df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5),
                     Distance = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971),
                     SpeedKph = c(75,70,80,71,83))

my.list <- list(list1 = my.df1, list2 = my.df2, list3 = my.df3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with `data.table` (which you are already using):

```
DT <- rbindlist(my.list, idcol = 'id')

DT[, grp := (id - 1) %/% 3
   ][, c(frames = toString(id), lapply(.SD, mean)), by = .(grp, ID), .SDcols = 3:4
     ][, dcast(.SD, frames ~ ID, value.var = c('Distance','SpeedKph'))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     frames Distance_1 Distance_2 Distance_3 Distance_4 Distance_5 SpeedKph_1 SpeedKph_2 SpeedKph_3 SpeedKph_4 SpeedKph_5
> 1: 1, 2, 3       2247   2247.000   1970.000   1964.000       1971   73.66667   72.00000   76.00000   72.33333   77.66667
> 2: 4, 5, 6       2229   2410.333   1962.667   1964.333       1966   74.66667   73.66667   77.33333   72.33333   77.66667
> ```

---

Extended example data:

```
my.df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Distance = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971), SpeedKph = c(73,73,74,73,75))
my.df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Distance = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971), SpeedKph = c(73,73,74,73,75))
my.df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Distance = c(2247,2247,1970,1964,1971), SpeedKph = c(75,70,80,71,83))
my.df4 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Distance = c(2247,2137,1948,1965,1971), SpeedKph = c(73,78,74,73,71))
my.df5 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Distance = c(2223,2247,1970,1964,1971), SpeedKph = c(76,73,74,73,79))
my.df6 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Distance = c(2217,2847,1970,1964,1956), SpeedKph = c(75,70,84,71,83))

my.list <- list(my.df1, my.df2, my.df3, my.df4, my.df5, my.df6)
```

---

---

In response the the comment:

```
# create some extra example data
my.df4a <- my.df4[-4,]
my.df5a <- my.df5[-c(4,5),]
my.df6a <- my.df6[-c(3,4),]
my.df7 <- my.df4[-c(4:6),]
my.df8 <- my.df5[-c(4:6),]
my.df9 <- my.df6[-c(4:6),]

# make another list of 9 dataframes
my.list2 <- list(my.df1, my.df2, my.df3, my.df4a, my.df5a, my.df6a, my.df7, my.df8, my.df9) 

# bind that list together in one data.table
DT2 <- rbindlist(my.list2, idcol = 'dfid')

# do an 'expand join' with 'CJ' and add the original transformation
DT2[CJ(dfid = dfid, ID = ID, unique = TRUE), on = .(dfid, ID)
    ][, grp := (dfid - 1) %/% 3
      ][, c(frames = toString(dfid), lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(grp, ID), .SDcols = 3:4
        ][, dcast(.SD, frames ~ ID, value.var = c('Distance','SpeedKph'))]
```

this gives:

> ```
>     frames Distance_1 Distance_2 Distance_3 Distance_4 Distance_5 SpeedKph_1 SpeedKph_2 SpeedKph_3 SpeedKph_4 SpeedKph_5
> 1: 1, 2, 3       2247   2247.000   1970.000       1964     1971.0   73.66667   72.00000   76.00000   72.33333   77.66667
> 2: 4, 5, 6       2229   2410.333   1959.000        NaN     1963.5   74.66667   73.66667   74.00000        NaN   77.00000
> 3: 7, 8, 9       2229   2410.333   1962.667        NaN        NaN   74.66667   73.66667   77.33333        NaN        NaN
> ```

---

---

With regard to row order:

```
my.df10 <- my.df4
my.df11 <- my.df5
my.df12 <- my.df6

my.list3 <- list(my.df1, my.df2, my.df3, my.df4a, my.df5a, my.df6a, my.df7, my.df8, my.df9, my.df10, my.df11, my.df12) 

DT3 <- rbindlist(my.list3, idcol = 'dfid')

DT3[CJ(dfid = dfid, ID = ID, unique = TRUE), on = .(dfid, ID)
    ][, grp := (dfid - 1) %/% 3
      ][, c(frames = toString(dfid), lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(grp, ID), .SDcols = 3:4
        ][, dcast(.SD, grp + frames ~ ID, value.var = c('Distance','SpeedKph'))]
```

this gives:

> ```
>    grp     frames Distance_1 Distance_2 Distance_3 Distance_4 Distance_5 SpeedKph_1 SpeedKph_2 SpeedKph_3 SpeedKph_4 SpeedKph_5
> 1:   0    1, 2, 3       2247   2247.000   1970.000   1964.000     1971.0   73.66667   72.00000   76.00000   72.33333   77.66667
> 2:   1    4, 5, 6       2229   2410.333   1959.000        NaN     1963.5   74.66667   73.66667   74.00000        NaN   77.00000
> 3:   2    7, 8, 9       2229   2410.333   1962.667        NaN        NaN   74.66667   73.66667   77.33333        NaN        NaN
> 4:   3 10, 11, 12       2229   2410.333   1962.667   1964.333     1966.0   74.66667   73.66667   77.33333   72.33333   77.66667
> ```

Comment: Hi Jaap, your solution is almost what I need, only it doesn't work when there is missing data; e.g. when (in this example) one of the 'my.df's' has less than 5 observations. I would my final data.frame to show NA if there was no observation in any of the three combined data.frames for that ID, if there is only one observations I would like it to state that observation and if there are two observations I would like it to state the average of the two observations. Could you help me with that?

Comment: greatly appreciated :) I've no clue where to start, how can I add the NA's/average over less than three observations to the code so it keeps three data.frames per row (currently it creates new rows if there is missing data)?

Comment: @RobinNico see the update; is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Excellent! Two final questions regarding ordering rows & columns:
- Columns: I have the column names in a vector 'columnorder', so I tried to order them with this piece of code: `DT2 <- setcolorder(DT2,columnorder)`. This worked before, however, no it doesn't. Do you know why?
- Rows: I would like to order my rows ascending order, with a dataset of e.g. 12 data.frames in a list the order gets messy (first 123, then 10-11-12, then 456, etc.), as R orders it based on the first number. Is there an easy way to order it based on the original order (123, 456, 789, 10-11-12)?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobinNico `setcolorder(DT2,columnorder)` should work, but if you are trying the reset the column order in the result with columnnames from the original file it won't work because those names are not present in the resulting data.table. With regard to the rows order, you could try to change the `dcast`-part to: `dcast(.SD, grp + frames ~ ID, value.var = c('Distance','SpeedKph'))`. Please let me know if that works (I haven't tried it myself yet)

Comment: Oke, I'm gonna try the column order once again. The row order, unfortunately, doesn't work with that piece of code...

Comment: if I run your code I get the erro **Error in check_formula(formula, names(data), valnames) : data.table to cast must have unique column names**. The only change I made is that I dropped 'Distance' from `value.var = c('Distance','SpeedKph')`, as I also deleted it from my list of data.frames as I don't use it anymore.

Comment: Only changed ID to SegmentID and dropped 'Distance'.
`DT3 <- rbindlist(fcdtest, idcol = 'dfid')
DT3[CJ(dfid = dfid, SegmentID = SegmentID, unique = TRUE), on = .(dfid, SegmentID)
    ][, grp := (dfid - 1) %/% 3
      ][, c(frames = toString(dfid), lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(grp, SegmentID), .SDcols = 3:4
        ][, dcast(.SD,  grp + frames ~ SegmentID, value.var = c('SpeedKph'))]`

Comment: @RobinNico What version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: I'm using version '1.10.0'

Comment: @RobinNico Could you upgrade? Current version is 1.10.4-3. See also [this issue on Github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1654). I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161873/discussion-between-robin-nico-and-jaap).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your full dataset, try the following:

**cut dataframe by 15s**

First add a column of `1:nrow(df)`, we'll use `1:1000` for this example.

```
require(tidyverse)    

DF <- data.frame(mean_speed = sample(40:100, 1000, replace = TRUE))

DF2 <- DF %>%
   mutate(index = 1:nrow(.),
   group = cut(index, c(seq(0, nrow(.), 15), nrow(.)))) %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%
   select(-index) %>%
   spread(row_num, mean_speed)
```

We end up cutting rows into a sequence broken out by 15s. Then we group it by that and set up the row number. This will put `1:15` for each group. Then we want to deselect everything but the group, and the mean. Lastly we spread to move the format to wide.

EDIT: given your updated info. I would try the following:

```
DF2 <- dfTotal %>%
  mutate(group = cut(ID, c(seq(0, nrow(.), 15), nrow(.)))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  select(-Distance) %>%
  spread(ID, SpeedKph)
```

The one thing I'm not sure about is if ID is 1:1000 in your larger dataframe, or if its 1:15. If you could provide your dataset with 50 rows, that would help. If ID is 1:15, you should be able to use the code above. If it's 1:1000, then you would need to add the `mutate(row_num = row_number())`

Comment: Thanks Matt! Could you elaborate on the first step:
DF <- data.frame(mean_speed = sample(40:100, 1000, replace = TRUE))
What is it that you do with 40:1000?

Comment: Sure - that was before you posted some of your data. I used it as a dummy DF just to show the logic of how to manipulate a similar looking dataframe. You would ignore that piece and apply the other code to your own dataset.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question/I wasn't clear enough. My dataset is a list with 1000 elements of type data.frame. Each data.frame has a maximum of 45 ID's (i.e. 45 rows, but in some minutes one or more ID's is missing, so it could be e.g. 35 rows). I want to combine and average the complete data set per 15 data.frames, add this in one data.frame and transpose the data.frame so that I've the ID's as columns and the average SpeedKph per 15min as rows. I'll edit and clarify my initial question as well